# Adding JButton dynamically to the JPanel not working with Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I created a `JFrame Class` with `Netbeans 7.3` and added two panels from the palette.
I have added a button in the first panel on the click of which I want to add a new button in the second panel(topoPane).

Below is the button click event that I have written for the same. But, the button is not getting added to the panel even when the event is getting called.
Please tell me what's wrong in it.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    System.out.println("Creating the Button");        
    JButton but = new JButton();
    but.setBackground(Color.red);
    but.setText("New Button");
    but.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);

    topoPane.add(but);
    topoPane.revalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your use of `setBounds`, it is obvious that you are using a `null` layout. Because of this you need to call `repaint()` as containers with no layout do not automatically repaint added components on `revalidate`.

Apart from the fact that calling `repaint` is good practice, layout managers *can* remove the need to make this call along with manage the sizing and positioning of components. This makes it a good reason to use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).